# How do I call a function with a STL iterator to work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std, stdvector

How do I get this to work?

```
for (auto i = m_vehicles.begin(); i != m_vehicles.end(); i++)
{
    *i->display(out);
    out << endl;
}
```

Where `m_vehicles` is a `vector<Vehicle*>` and `display` in `Vehicle` is
`virtual void display(std::ostream&) const = 0;`.

Current Visual Studio error is "Expression must have a pointer to class type"

(`out` is just an `ostream`)

Comment: Instead of describing it, why not show a minimal `Vehicle` class?

Comment: You're almost right, just check your operator precedence.

Comment: `(*i)->display(out)`